# Extracting parameter names in nested functions in R

Tags: r, function, nested, lazy-evaluation, variable-names

I would like to extract the name of a function parameter as a string.

It works fine unless the function is called from within another function (see below).

There must be a simple solution for this, just cannot seem to find one.

```r
library(reprex)
print_data_1 <- function(DATA) {
  DATA_txt <- deparse(substitute(DATA))
  print(DATA_txt)
}

print_data_2 <- function(DF) {
  print_data_1(DF)
}

print_data_1(mi_d)
#> [1] "mi_d"
print_data_2(mi_d)
#> [1] "DF"
```

`print_data_2` should return "mi_d".

<sup>Created on 2021-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `rlang`. This stuff gets pretty advanced in a hurry.

```r
library(rlang)

print_data_1 <- function(DATA) {
  .DATA <- enquo(DATA)
  .DATA_txt <- as_name(.DATA)
  
  print(.DATA_txt)
}

print_data_2 <- function(DF) {
  .DF <- enquo(DF)
  
  print_data_1(!!.DF)
}

print_data_1(mi_d)
#> [1] "mi_d"
print_data_2(mi_d)
#> [1] "mi_d"
```

And so on...

```r
print_data_3 <- function(X) {
  .X <- enquo(X)
  
  print_data_2(!!.X)
}

print_data_3(mi_d)
#> [1] "mi_d"
```

- `enquo()` will quote the user argument.
- `!!` will unquote the argument into the function.
- `as_name()` will convert the quoted argument into character.

The [cheatsheet](https://github.com/rstudio/cheatsheets/raw/master/tidyeval.pdf) is pretty helpful, as are the `rlang` vignettes.

To get the value of that object back, you can use `eval_tidy()` on the *quosure*.

```r
print_data_1 <- function(DATA) {
  .DATA <- enquo(DATA)
  .DATA_txt <- as_name(.DATA)
  
  df <- eval_tidy(.DATA)
  
  print(.DATA_txt)
  df
}

print_data_2(mtcars)
```

Comment: Appreciated! And if I would like to use the dataframe "mi_d" inside "print_data_1", how would I do that?  I would need to refer to the dataframe as text and in some other parts of the function refer to it as a data frame.

Comment: Well, you can just use the `DATA` variable on its own. Or you can use `!!` to unquote it inside of a function. Or you can use `eval_tidy()` on the quosure.

Comment: Exactly what i needed.